# When is the new style applied in an HTML Form

Tags: javascript, html, css

It's very interesting how does browser engine works in this situation, because I test it in IE, Firefox and Chrome and they all works differently. For example:

```
<style>
.parent{
width:100px;
}
.expand{
width:200px;
}
</style>

<div class="parent">
<div class="child"></div>
</div>

<input type="button" id="btn" />

<script>
//onready
$('#btn').click(function(){
$('.parent').toggleClass('expand');
alert($('.child').width());
});
</script>
```

The problem is in chrome. I don't know why but ('.child').width() is always old value, but not a new width of his parent. When and how does recalculating for width works?

Comment: You should work on your accept rating. You have some questions with answers that you might like to accept in order to improve your rating and thus heighten the chance to get a decent answer.

Answer (score 7):

> When and how does recalculating for width works?

As you've found, it can be browser-dependent.

If you give the browser a moment to do its work by releasing the JavaScript thread, you see the new value:

```
$('#btn').click(function(){
    $('.parent').toggleClass('expand');
    setTimeout(function() {
        alert($('.child').width());
    }, 0);
});
```

[Live Example](http://jsbin.com/igofub/2) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/igofub/2/edit) *(see also the notes below)*

The delay won't really be 0 milliseconds, of course, but it'll be very brief indeed.

---

Separately, this line

```
$('parent').toggleClass('expand');
```

should be

```
$('.parent').toggleClass('expand');
```

(Note the leading `.`)

...and I should note that for me, on Chrome for Linux, it works without the timeout: [Example](http://jsbin.com/igofub/1) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/igofub/1/edit)

Comment: What about '.parent' it's just mistake in example, coz it's not a copy paste. The main idea of this topic is how can I know when I will get right dimensions after layout was changed?

Comment: @Garik: I figured (although it's usually best to actually use copy and paste -- first make your example, then when it demonstrates what you're seeing, post that via copy-and-paste). The main idea of the answer is `setTimeout(function() { /* now it's updated */ }, 0);` Just give the browser a moment to do its thing and call you back.

Comment: Thank you, next time, I'll make copy paste. Is it possible to force recalculating? Who is responsible for this? Is it some standards of how it should work?

Comment: @Garik: As far as I know, there's no way to make your JavaScript code stop in the middle of a function and tell the browser to recalculate everything if it hasn't already done so. That's what the `setTimeout` above does (but in a different way). I don't *think* when the UA recalculates is subject to any specifications or standards.